# How to revert from 14.04 back to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, graphics

My first Ubuntu installation was 12.04 LTS about a month ago on the desktop PC detailed below. This worked well but I forgot that *if it works don't try to fix it* and I upgraded to 14.04 LTS. Unfortunately this gives frequent *...Internal Error ...* messages and occasionally freezes. I was learning to live with these hiccups but the latest problem is that the graphics have some how degraded to looking quite "chunky" and movement of windows around the screen is very slow.
My preferred solution for now would be to revert back from 14.04LTS to 12.04LTS. Is this possible?

System details:
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz × 4
Graphics: VESA: G86 Board - p403h10 
Monitor: Flatron L225WS

Many thanks, Arnie

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would simply recommend you backup your files, wipe, install 12.04, and restore your files. However, there may be a more streamlined, albeit complicated, process as found: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto).

Comment: Thanks CarrotIsland, your solution sounds more straightforward to this novice so I'll give it a try ...